# json element value to be replaced with variable in shell script

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a template json file with list of hosts for an example. The same to be replaced with the dynamic value being generated by shell script.

Sample rds.json

```json
{
    "lob": "coaching",
    "function": "badminton",
    "hosts": [
        "node1.rds.sports.com",
        "node2.rds.sports.com",
        "node3.rds.sports.com"
        ],
    "adminserver": "node1.rds.sports.com",
    "user_name": "coach",
    "sudo_type": "sudo",
    "group_name": "admin"
}
```

`echo $myHosts`:

`"host1.rds.sports.com", "host2.rds.sports.com", "host3.rds.sports.com", "host4.rds.sports.com", "host5.rds.sports.com", "host6.rds.sports.com", "host7.rds.sports.com", "host8.rds.sports.com"`

The value of $myHosts should get replaced in hosts elements key.

Desired output:

```json
{
    "lob": "coaching",
    "function": "badminton",
    "hosts": [
        "host1.rds.sports.com", 
        "host2.rds.sports.com", 
        "host3.rds.sports.com", 
        "host4.rds.sports.com", 
        "host5.rds.sports.com", 
        "host6.rds.sports.com", 
        "host7.rds.sports.com", 
        "host8.rds.sports.com"
    ],
    "adminserver": "hosts1.rds.sports.com",
    "user_name": "coach",
    "sudo_type": "sudo",
    "group_name": "admin"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the contents of `myHosts` is a valid JSON array body.

```sh
jq --argjson hosts "[$myHosts]" '.hosts = $hosts | .adminserver = .hosts[0]' rds.json
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/vfMBeknFGG)

Comment: The o/p of the jq command is coming with the updated list but the file is not getting updated.

Comment: @RajeswaraRaoAyyalasomayajula - See "Q: How can "in-place" editing of a JSON file be accomplished?" in the jq FAQ: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ